# How to guarantee execution of ABAP code 'only' once at a given time across sessions via background job?

Tags: abap, jobs

I have a program where multiple jobs are launched in background mode and they all process a certain method - SAVE_DATA - in the processing flow of the program. There is a separate identifier for each job and at a given time only one identifier can process the code within the SAVE_DATA method . So how do I restrict the other jobs from  processing this method if each of the job is independent and exclusive but have only this dependency that at a 'given point' only one identifier can process this method.

I tried obtaining an exclusive lock on a table at the start of the SAVE_DATA method and releasing at the end of the method. This works fine except in scenarios where all the background jobs launched end up at the 'check point' at the same time. This is a very high possibility and the lock logic goes for a toss .  Is there something else I can do in the above scenario to GUARANTEE than the  SAVE_DATA method is processed one at a time across different processes ?

Kindly let me know if you need more information .

So here's the pseudo-logic am using to 'obtain' the lock at the start of the method .

```
check_flag = 'X' .

while check_flag is not initial .

  call function 'ENQUEUE_READ'
    exporting
     gclient                     = sy-mandt
     gname                       = 'RSTABLE'
*    GARG                        = ' '
     guname                      = sy-uname
*    LOCAL                       = ' '
*    FAST                        = ' '
*    GARGNOWC                    = ' '
* IMPORTING
*   NUMBER                         =
*   SUBRC                          =
tables
  enq                          = lt_seqg3
* EXCEPTIONS
*   COMMUNICATION_FAILURE          = 1
*   SYSTEM_FAILURE                 = 2
  .

if lt_seqg3[] is initial . "implies no lock obtained by any identifier .

  clear check_flag .

*obtain the lock for the table UNIQUE_TABLE_WITH_IDENTIFIER with the current identifier as key

  lv_key = UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER

  call function 'ENQUEUE_E_TABLE'
  exporting
    mode_rstable         = 'E'
    tabname              = UNIQUE_TABLE_WITH_IDENTIFIER 
    varkey               = lv_key
    x_tabname            = ' '
    x_varkey             = ' '
    _scope               = '2'
    _wait                = ' '
    _collect             = ' '
  exceptions
    foreign_lock         = 1
    system_failure       = 2
    .

endif.
<some logging > 
endwhile.
```

Question : Is there a way to prevent multiple IDENTIFIERS from obtaining the lock ? All the IDENTIFIERS are in different background jobs simultaneously launched and seems to end up at the check point at the same time so the 'ENQUEUE_READ' seems to not work as desired .

Comment: If the "lock logic goes for a toss" as you put it, it's likely you didn't implement it correctly. Locking (via enqueue objects) should be the way to go. Without further information, it's not possible to tell what went wrong.

Comment: @vwegert : Hi ,have added the pseudo logic of how am currently obtaining the locks. Guess am doing something silly . Can you kindly have a look ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is broken. Calling the generated `ENQUEUE` function module is guaranteed to be atomic - the system either returns without an exception and the lock is set, or you get an exception and you don't have a lock set. Any other operation is **not** guaranteed to be atomic, so that other processes can sneak in between and steal your lock. What you're currently doing amounts to the following:

- Check if a lock is set
- Give other processes ample time to claim a foreign lock
- Then try to obtain a lock
- Continue without checking if you really got one

You don't need to check anything beforehand - I've never even used `ENQUEUE_READ` in real applications. Just call `ENQUEUE_E_TABLE` and **check the return values, especially `sy-subrc`** - if it is zero, and **only then**, continue.